# Can I Rearrange This Equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not the best at math, and I'm trying to build an equation for an Excel/Sheets file.

Here's my equation:

$E=(A*B)+((D*B)*C)$

Is it possible to move the $B$ variable to be by itself on the left side of the equation?

I'm at my wits' end trying to figure this out, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do all those letters stand for numbers? Does writing two of them next to each other signify multiplication? Does the asterisk also signify multiplication? If the answers are all yes, you can use the distributive law to factor $B$ out from the right side, and then divide both sides by that coefficient of $B$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the answer to all of those questions is yes. Do you mind going a little more in depth on how to use the distributive law? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on Gerry Myerson's suggestion, you have successively, using commutativity, associativity and distributivity,
$$
E=(A*B)+((D*B)*C) = (B*A)+(B*C*D) = B*(A+(C*D))
$$
Now, if $A + (C*D)$ is not null, you can write $B = E/(A + (C*D))$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exact help that I needed.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

$$E=(A\cdot B) + ((D\cdot B)\cdot C$$

can be transformed to

$$ E= B\cdot(A+D\cdot C)$$

Thus,

$$ B = \frac{E}{A+D\cdot C}$$